# Change the position of button text and button icon

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a button which contains an icon and some text.  I want this button to be reusable.  I also want to have the option of putting the icon left of the text or right of the text.  I am passing in a prop (either "right" or "left") which will then adjust the CSS.  Could anyone help me out with the CSS to swap the position of these two.

```
export const IconButton = ({icon,text, position}) => {
  return (
    <StyledIconButton className={position}>
      <img src={icon} />
      {text}
    </StyledIconButton>
  );
};
```

The `StyledIconButton` has a few default styles, but nothing important.

I am trying to use float but haven't been successful.  Ideally I would avoid using flexbox as well.

```
.right {
   img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.375rem;
  }
}
.left {
  img {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

As requested I am adding in the styles for `StyledIconButton`:

```
.styledbutton {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}
```

The above code won't actually swap the position.

Comment: those "but nothing important" styles are most probably very important. I assume it uses flexbox and you might be able to override it by setting the `order` property. Otherwise please create a fully reusable jsfiddle for us to replicate

Comment: Hi @japrescott I updated the code to show the styles on StyledIconButton

Comment: You already in flex... Just use flex direction instead, and yes it was important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a flexbox and switching the direction would be the easiest way. You can learn about flexbox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).

But you can set left and right classes to decide on the direction of the flex.

```
.right {
   flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.left {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

And you would have set spacing and all other required styles on text and img separately, but this should do the trick